# how to split input to two pipes

Tags: command-line, pipe

I would like to do something equivalent to this:

```
some-expensive-command > /tmp/mytempfile
grep -v "pattern" /tmp/mytempfile >> output.txt
grep "pattern" /tmp/mytempfile | yet-another-command
```

Preferably elegant and without the need for the `tempfile`. I was thinking about piping through `tee`, but the best I can think of might is to combine two of the three lines and *still* require the intermediate storage:

```
some-expensive-command | tee /tmp/mytempfile | grep -v "pattern" >> output.txt
grep "pattern" /tmp/mytempfile | yet-another-command
```

Comment: So you want one command's output saved to file `output.txt`  and that same output redirected to another command for further processing ?  Is that what you're trying to do ?

Answer (score 9):

The way question reads it sounds like you want [one stdin redirected to two different commands](https://superuser.com/a/557291/418028). If that's the case, take advantage of `tee` plus process substitution:

```
some-expensive-command | tee >(grep 'pattern' > output.txt) >(grep -v 'pattern' | another-command)
```

Process substitutions are in fact anonymous pipelines implemented within bash itself ( on subprocess level ). We can also make the use of a named pipeline + `tee`. For instance, in terminal A do

```
$ mkfifo named.fifo
$ cat /etc/passwd | tee named.fifo | grep 'root'
```

And in another terminal B do

```
$ grep -v 'root' named.fifo
```

---

Another way to look at this is by recognizing that `grep` is *line* pattern matching tool, so by reading line at a time and using that same line in multiple commands we can achieve exactly the same effect:

```bsh
rm output.txt # get rid of file so that we don't add old and new output
some-expensive-command | while IFS= read -r line || [ -n "$line" ]; do
    printf "%s\n" "$line" | grep 'pattern' >> output.txt
    printf "%s\n" "$line" | grep -v 'pattern' | another-command
done
# or if another-command needs all of the output, 
# place `| another-comand` after `done` clause
```

---

Yet another way is to abandon `grep` and use something more powerful, like `awk`:

```
some-expensive-command | awk '/pattern/{print >> "output.txt"}; !/pattern/{print}' | another-command.
```

Practically speaking, don't worry about using temporary files, so long as you clean them up after using. If it works, it works.

Comment: .. *n*x / FLOSS toolchains are just so amazing! Thanks also for coming up with adequate alternatives..

Answer (score 2):

Use [`bash` Process Substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst):

```bsh
some-command | tee >(grep "pat" | another-command >>out1) | grep -v "pat" >>out2
```

The process substitution assigns `some-command`’s output to `grep "pat"`’s input, thus saving you the tempfile. Of course the data is still saved in a file (it’s always), just that you don’t have to take care of that. If you don’t want to save `another-command`’s output in a file but rather print it I recommend to simply switch the two command lists.

Another nice source of information: [`man bash`/EXPANSION](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/bash.1.html#expansion)